# use smsgateway result object

Tags: php, sms-gateway

i am following this link [send sms with smsgateway php](https://smsgateway.me/sms-api-documentation/devices/searching-android-devices)

and getting Successful response. But unable to get result object->id . Example result object looks like this

```
SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\Device Object
(
[id:protected] => 1
[name:protected] => Device Name
[attributes:protected] => SMSGatewayMe\Client\Model\DeviceAttributes Object
    (
        [phoneNumber:protected] => 07791064781
        [make:protected] => samsung
        [model:protected] => SM-G965F
        [provider:protected] => EE
        [country:protected] => gb
        [connectionType:protected] => 4G
        [battery:protected] => 43
        [signalPercent:protected] =>
        [wifi:protected] =>
        [lat:protected] => 52.6076925
        [lng:protected] => -0.2046643
        [lastSeen:protected] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-05-14 17:36:20.000000
                [timezone_type] => 1
                [timezone] => +00:00
            )

    )

)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i can see from the lib you need to call getId

```
$device->getId();
```

for the rest of the property you use getPropertyName

[more info](https://github.com/smsgatewayme/client-php/blob/master/lib/Model/Device.php)